# Application Of Derivatives - tangent questions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A curve in the co-ordinate plane is given by the parametric equation $x = t^2 + t + 2$ and $y = t^2− t + 2$ where $t \geq 0$. The number of straight lines passing through the point $(2, 2)$ which are tangent to the curve is/are?

I found the slope of tangent $\frac{dy}{dx}= 2t-\frac{1}{2t}+1$
and equation of the tangent as $y-(t^2-t+2)=(2t-\frac{1}{2t}+1)(x-(t^2+t+2))$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: found the slope of the tangent . found the equation. now i am unable to proceed further.

Comment: @BornilBuragohain: Please edit your question to include that work.

Comment: I'm sorry , what do i need to include?

Comment: You need to include the slope, equation you found. You can do so by clicking on the 'edit' button that's in the bottom left corner of the post just above your profile picture.

Comment: i included that . please help me now.

Comment: A curve given parametrially is a function mapping a single variable $t$ to a point in the $x,y$ plane. Your curve is $w(t)=(t^2+t+2,t^2-t+2).$ To get the derivative one just takes the derivative of the components (separately) of the curve. You did not do that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not able to catch the hint, here is the complete  solution

The slope of the tangent at the point $'t'$ would be given by

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{2t-1}{2t+1}$

The point $(2,2)$ lies on the curve which corresponds to $t=0$.

Therefore $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $(2,2)$ is $-1$ ( By putting $t=0$). Now you can find equation of tangent at point $(2,2)$ which is  $y-2=(-1)(x-2)$.

There would be only one tangent passing through the point $(2,2)$ because it lies on the given curve and derivative at this point exists.